# Jquery- Get the text area value including line breaks to tokenize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, textarea

I have a text area and I have IPs in that like

```
162.0.0.1
162.220.0.1
162.220.0.2
162.250.1.0
```

Now I want to get the text of this text area and send it via ajax call. Like

```
$('#ping_server').on('click', function () {
    var ips =   $('#ips').text();

    console.info(ips);

    $.ajax({
        url     :   'ping.php?ips='+ips,
        success :   function (result) {
            console.info(result);
        }
    });
});
```

How can I get the IPs and loop on them in php?

Comment: It seems you already got the text of text area, and sent it to the backend. so you are asking how to loop each IP from `?ips=`?

Comment: yes exactly. I am getting it as a string, How can I loop through it?

Comment: You may wish to collect those ips as an array and send them as part of the `$.ajax` data element instead of on the get string. It'll remove the extra complication of url-encoding issues and/or differences between jQuery and php.